# Not able to convert number in Date format

Tags: r, date, datetime

I need to convert string value "1515511826000" which is actually date but not in correct format. I need to change it in date format.

Date was previously saved in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. I want to convert value in same "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format using R. Original date is "January 9th 2018, 00:00:00.000"

Comment: Can you show desired output with the example you gave.

Comment: even as Unix time, that corresponds to year 49994... seems unlikely...

Comment: What information is in the string? "days since ..." or "seconds since ..." or "weeks since ..."

Comment: It`s a publication date which was originally saved in year, month, day hour, minute and second (example: '2002-04-02 00:00:00'). It got converted in number while reading it in R.

Comment: And with origin "01-01-01", it is `"48025-08-29"`.

Comment: Kiwi show me how  "1515511826000" should look.

Comment: @Kiwi Please put the additional information in your question - not in a comment! I.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48829012/edit

Comment: leeum: January 9th 2018, 00:00:00.000

Comment: I have posted a possible answer (correct data in output), but the number 1515511826000 is suspect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
as.POSIXct(1515511826, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2018-01-09 16:30:26 CET"
```

In your example your date 1515511826000 has too many zeros at the end....

Comment: Thanks..!! I am also not sure why original data has extra zeros at the end. The original data looks like "January 9th 2018, 00:00:00.000"

Comment: Where is done this conversion to number?

Comment: While extracting data from FTP using Jupyter note(Elastic search)

Comment: But at least with your code I am able to get date which is matching with original date. Thank you..!!

Comment: You can use this date_standard<-(floor(date/(1000*60*60*24))*(60*60*24)-60*60) to come back to standard date and have this January 9th 2018, 00:00:00.000 in output

Comment: what value i should put for date in above formula?

Comment: date<-1515511826000

Comment: The output is "1515452400". What does it mean?

Comment: If you put date_standard in as.POSIXct(date_standard, origin="1970-01-01") you will have in output: January 9th 2018, 00:00:00.000  without hour and minutes, but I don't know if you want this...

Comment: Yes, it works for me..Thank you again!!

Comment: You are welcome!